# partial parameter list injection on play framework

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

given a class

```
class Foo @Inject()(cfg: Config, private val emr: AmazonElasticMapReduce = AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder.defaultClient())
                             (implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem, ec: ExecutionContext)
```

play framework fails when it tries to Inject the 'emr' value.

I don't want play to inject it, instead I want to use the default value.
Is it possible to define?

Comment: @TomerShetah yes. thanks! Basically i wanted to avoid injection
what i did eventually was to add another constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to your `Module.scala`:

```
bind(classOf[AmazonElasticMapReduce]).toInstance(AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder.defaultClient()).asEagerSingleton()
```

Instead of trying to provide it to the constructor.

If you don't want it injected at all, you can have it just as a member in the class.